retrieving the index of subset assignment inside the replacement function
Assume we have the following replacement function foo<-:
foo <- function(x) {
  x
}

`foo<-` <- function(x, value) {
  value
}

x <- 1:3
foo(x)[2] <- 40
x
[1]  1 40  3

This can have unwanted effects if the subset index is out of scope.
x <- 1:3
foo(x)[-5] <- 40
x
[1] 40 40 40

Thus, I would like to intercept the subset index and do some checks with it inside foo<-.
In the R Lang Definition, section 3.4.4 Subset assignment, it is described that the above would be roughly equivalent to
x <- 1:3
`*tmp*` <- x
x <- "foo<-"(`*tmp*`, value="[<-"(foo(`*tmp*`), -5, value=40))
rm(`*tmp*`)

This would mean the subset index is processed in a call to [<- before calling foo<-.
Is retrieving the index i = -5 from this call still somehow possible from inside foo<-?

NB: I cannot / do not want to assign a class to x and create a [<-.foo method, for example, like this:

# I cannot add a class attribute, so this is not possible:
foo <- function(x) {
  class(x) <- c("foo", class(x))
  x
}

`[<-.foo` <- function(x, i, value) {
  cat("index: ", i, "\n")
  # <<< do something with i >>>
  NextMethod("[<-")
}

x <- 1:3
foo(x)[1] <- 40
x


If you change the syntax like this then the index can be captured: "foo<-" <- function(x, i, value) replace(x, print(i), value); x <- 1:4; foo(x, 2) <- 40

The call to <- and the implicit, intermediate call to [<- have no associated "context"; they do not appear on the call stack.  So I suspect that the answer subject to the stated constraints is really "no".  You can see this by debugging into foo and evaluating sys.calls().  There is a section on contexts in the R Internals manual.
